# Build the binary problem with TensorFlow Lite and SparkFun Edge

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I would like to use TensorFlow Lite with the board Sparkfun Edge. I try to follow  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sparkfun-tensorflow/#3 but when I must build the binary, I can't compile. I have a error. I use this command

```sh
make -f tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/Makefile TARGET=sparkfun_edge micro_speech_bin
```

This command must download all of the required dependencies and initiate the build process. However it seems that there is a problem during this process and all dependencies are not download.
I don't know if someone know what I can do to resolve my problem...

I'm working on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04.

I have this error:

```sh
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/downloads/gcc_embedded//lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/micro_speech/Makefile.inc:372: recipe for target 'tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/gen/sparkfun_edge_cortex-m4/bin/micro_speech' failed
make: *** [tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/gen/sparkfun_edge_cortex-m4/bin/micro_speech] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. This worked for me :
Edit the file apollo3evb_makefile.inc

- Line 12, Make sure GCC_ARM points to the ARM compiler (mine are not in $(MAKEFILE_DIR)/downloads/gcc_embedded/)
- Line 87 , change the version number to match your version (I have the latest 8.3.1, the original file had 7.3.1)
  $(GCC_ARM)/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/crtbegin.o \

I can build the binary now